# why gcc 6.4.0 c++14 moves automatically lvalue to rvalue

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, move-assignment-operator, lvalue-to-rvalue

I encountered a problem where gcc compiler moved local variable (not temporary) as rvalue argument to a function.
I have a simple example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}

    A& operator=(const A&) { std::cout << "const A&\n"; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&&) { std::cout << "A&&\n"; return *this; }
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {}

    B& operator=(const B&) { std::cout << "const B&\n"; return *this; }
    B& operator=(B&&) { std::cout << "B&&\n"; return *this; }

    template<class T> B& operator=(const T&) { std::cout << "const T& (T is " << typeid(T).name() << ")\n"; return *this; }
    template<class T> B& operator=(T&&) { std::cout << "T&& (T is " << typeid(T).name() << ")\n"; return *this; }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A a1;
    A a2;

    a1 = a2;

    B b1;
    B b2;

    std::cout << "B is " << typeid(B).name() << "\n";

    b1 = b2;
}
```

The output:

```
const A&
B is 1B
T&& (T is 1B)
```

I did not expect it because move assignment zeros the rvalue. In my case it caused to crash because b2 was used in after b1=b2;

The question is why it happened.

Comment: I don't see any "zeros the rvalue" in the code you show. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: One line after `b1=b2` `b2` will be deleted, so why not optimize the code and use a move instead of a copy? Looks like a clever optimization to me.

Comment: Oh and if you need help with a crash in your code, then please ask about it directly instead. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: read about reference collapsing and perfect forwarding

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class T> B& operator=(T&&)
{ std::cout << "T&& (T is " << typeid(T).name() << ")\n"; return *this; }
```

is not a move assignment operator because it's a template. From N4140, [[class.copy]/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#19)

> A user-declared move assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static **non-template member function** of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X&&`, `const X&&`, `volatile X&&`, or `const volatile X&&`.

You've defined an assignment operator template that takes a [forwarding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/241631). In the line

```
b1 = b2;
```

the `operator=(T&&)` template is a better match than the copy assignment operator (`B& operator=(const B&)`) because `T` will be deduced as `B&` and no `const` qualification conversion is required.

If you replace the calls to `typeid`, which discards references, with Boost.TypeIndex this becomes apparent.

```
template<class T> B& operator=(T&&) 
{ 
  std::cout << "T&& (T is " << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name() << ")\n";
  return *this;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac2cd9910aa5de70)

The output changes to

```
const A&
B is B
T&& (T is B&)
```

---

If you don't want `operator=(T&&)` to be selected, you can constrain it so it's dropped from overload resolution if `T=B`

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same<B, std::decay_t<T>>{}, int> = 0>
B& operator=(T&&) 
{ 
    std::cout << "T&& (T is " << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name() << ")\n"; 
    return *this; 
}
```

(you may want to use `is_convertible` instead of `is_same` if inheritance is involved)

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b702f2128818929)

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that T& && can be